# Spread operator in Vuex not compiling correctly with babel, I keep getting module build failed

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I am using a spread operator in my mapGetters object.  I am aware that you need to use a specific babel-preset-stage to compile ES6 properly.  I npm installed babel-preset-stage-2 and was getting this error still.

```
ERROR in ./~/babel-loader/lib!./~/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0!./src/components/AnotherResult.vue
Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token (13:8)

  11 | export default {
  12 |     computed: {
> 13 |         ...mapGetters ([
     |         ^
  14 |             'doubleCounter',
  15 |             'stringCounter'
  16 |     ])
```

I have looked around on the github and it seems like this is a common problem and it looks like people suggested to try babel-preset-stage-3 and other webpack configurations.

Here is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "vue-cli",
  "description": "A Vue.js project",
  "author": "Maximilian Schwarzmüller <mblacky0@gmail.com>",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --open --inline --hot",
    "build": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --progress --hide-modules"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "vue": "^2.0.1",
    "vue-router": "^2.0.1",
    "vuex": "^3.1.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "^6.0.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.0.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-3": "^6.24.1",
    "cross-env": "^3.0.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.25.0",
    "file-loader": "^0.9.0",
    "vue-loader": "^9.7.0",
    "webpack": "2.1.0-beta.25",
    "webpack-dev-server": "2.1.0-beta.0"
  }
}
```

.babelrc file

```
{
    "presets": [
        ["es2015", {"modules": false}],
        ["stage-3", "env"]
    ],
    "plugins": ["transform-object-rest-spread"]
}
```

It still doesn't want to compile under these new configurations.  Any insight would be appreciated please?

Thanks

Comment: I think latest version of Vue CLI (`@vue/cli` package) generates a totally different package.json file. Babel is also preconfigured in the generated project. So you probably want to save some time and upgrade to the latest version anyways. Try installing `@vue/cli` and then run `vue ui` and then use the wizard to generate your new project. Everything should work out of the box.

Comment: @fardjad are you talking about the package-lock-json file?  if I am using npm, how would I install this?

Comment: No, you want to install the latest version of the `@vue/cli` package globally (run `npm install -g @vue/cli`). Then cd to the directory you want your project to be created (ex. `cd /path/to/your/user/profile/directory/Desktop`) and run `vue ui`. Visit [this](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/creating-a-project.html#using-the-gui) link for more info.

Comment: Also, To avoid conflicts with previously installed `vue-cli` package and in order to use the latest LTS version of node when running the cli, make sure you have the latest version of npm installed (`npm install -g npm`), and then run `npx -p node@lts -p @vue/cli vue ui` (or you can just uninstall the old package and install `@vue/cli` package globally as explained in the official docs)

Comment: Have you imported mapGetters from Vuex in your component?

Comment: Seems like a [known issue](https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/7525) with older Webpack versions, resolved with Webpack 4+. Try updating that dep.

Comment: Hi @tony19 I checked the version and low and behold
```Brians-MacBook-Pro:Vuex briansantos$ npm list webpack
vue-cli@ /Users/briansantos/code/Vuex
└── webpack@2.1.0-beta.25
```
whats the easiest way to go from 2.0 to 4.0 I've seen the docs about going from 3.0 to 4.0, is it still the same?

Comment: @muka.gergely Yes I made sure to import mapGetters from Vuex in my component.

Comment: @brianmsantos I'd follow the Webpack docs for [migrating to 3](https://webpack.js.org/migrate/3), and then [to 4](https://webpack.js.org/migrate/4).

Answer (score 1):

I try with this setup and for me work

babel.rc:

```
{
  "presets": [
    ["es2015", { "modules": false }],
    ["stage-2"]
  ]
}
```

package.json

```
"devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "^6.0.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.0.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.24.1",
    "cross-env": "^3.0.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.25.0",
    "file-loader": "^0.9.0",
    "vue-loader": "^9.7.0",
    "webpack": "2.1.0-beta.25",
    "webpack-dev-server": "2.1.0-beta.0"
  }
```

webpack.config.js

```
{
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel',
        exclude: /node_modules/
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Spreading is an `es6` functionality hence not supported in the browsers so use `babel` to transpile it for the browser to understand:
Do this-

1. run `npm i babel-preset-stage-2`
2. in the `.babelrc` file add

   {
   "presets": ["stage-2"]
   }
3. run `npm run dev` to transpile the code